# Register user fingerprint in android application

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api, rsa-key-fingerprint

Is it possible to register user's fingerprint in an android application (not in settings)and store it in the database and later use the database for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Android-native fingerprint authentication is only for authenticating the user to the device. While apps can ask to re-affirm that authentication, apps cannot collect fingerprint data themselves, let alone use that data later.